# Ubuntu Updates Cause NGINX Lockup

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I've encountered and issue with 2 different nginx/Ubuntu based Load Balancers this week, hoping someone might be able to help.

Each machine has received the following updates in the past 24 hours
[apt update log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljbdY.png)

That has caused nginx to stop accepting traffic, subsequently causing an outage.

running " service nginx status " still shows as "green" with the Service running, and an uptime of since the last OS Reboot. This I think is causing keepalived to believe it's still operating and not failing over to the 2nd LB.
However, performing service ngninx restart immediately solves the issue and the site is available again within a second or 2.

Has anyone has experience of these updates causing nginx to "lock up" or can offer any advice?

Thanks to the community here as always.

Adam

Comment: Forgot to put - did TOP at the time of issue and nothing was CPU hogging

Comment: systemd was updated? Anything that links to it (such as nginx) also usually needs to be restarted. Usually best to just reboot when systemd is updated.

Comment: That would explain it. Thank You Michael, still relatively new to the Linux world but reading that that Driver does, logical that it would cause harm to services. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please see Comment

systemd was updated? Anything that links to it (such as nginx) also usually needs to be restarted. Usually best to just reboot when systemd is updated. – Michael Hampton Jul 23 at 13:00

Credit and Thanks to Michael Hampton